# Consistency of regression function estimate

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, machine-learning, regression

This question is in the context of regression with squared error loss.

Let $(X,Y) \in \mathbb{R}^p\times\mathbb{R}$ be random variables with joint distribution ${F}$. We randomly sample a training set of $n$ i.i.d observations $D_n = \{(X_i,Y_i): i = 1,\ldots,n\}$.

Let's assume $D_n$ is a fixed realization for now. The goal is to learn a function $m_n(X; D_n)$ from the observed training set that is stochastically "close" to $Y$ in the sense that $L_n = \mathbb{E}[(m_n(X;D_n) - Y)^2)|D_n]$ is minimized. It is well-known that $m^*(X) = \mathbb{E}[Y|X] = \underset{m}{\arg\min}\, \mathbb{E}[(m(X) - Y)^2]$, and we say that the Bayes Error is $L^* = \mathbb{E}[(m^*(X) - Y)^2]$. Hence, $L_n \geq L^*$

Now to my question:

Assume $D_n$ is no longer fixed (i.e. it's a random variable), and therefore $L_n$ is random (through $D_n$). Suppose our procedure for learning $m_n(X;D_n)$ from the training data is consistent, in the sense that $m_n(X;D_n) \xrightarrow{P} m^*(X)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Does this imply that $L_n \xrightarrow{P} L^*$?

=======================

My thoughts on approaching the problem:

Note that $g(m_n(X;D_n)) = (m_n(X;D_n) - Y)^2$ is a continuous function of $m_n(X;D_n)$. Therefore it seems like the answer to my question might be yes, via the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem). However, $L_n$ is defined as the conditional expectation of $g$ given $D_n$, which makes me unsure if it applies.

Comment: Get Casella and Berger's intro stats book or van der Vaart's Asymptotic Stats and stop reading machine learning people for stats material. If you go to Amazon and look at the first pages of their preview for Asymptotic Stats, it might resolve a lot of your confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the reading suggestions. I have looked through Bickel and Doksum's Mathematical Statistics book, as well as Devroye, Gyorfi, and Lugosi's A probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition. I used both of these in grad courses I took. I could not find anything that eludes to an answer to my question, unfortunately. I will check out the books you suggested.